# MapViewOfFile-OpenFileMapping (need help)

Tags: c, windows

``i'm try to do my homework, but i cant continue,need your help.
i have two processes which use same file (log.txt). when i tyr to write something at the same time, it overwrites and ONLY ONE  process write to txt.

This my creater process,

```
enter code here
     #include <Windows.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
       #include "..\\def.h"



      int main(){

HANDLE hReadPipe;
HANDLE hWritePipe;
HANDLE hMMap;
DWORD bytesWritten;
HANDLE hFile;
STARTUPINFO si_e;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi_e;

STARTUPINFO si_d;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi_d;


SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;

sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);

    if(!CreatePipe(&hReadPipe,&hWritePipe, &sa,0))
    fprintf(stderr,"Unable to create pipe.\n");
ZeroMemory(&si_e, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
ZeroMemory(&si_d, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));



if((hFile =CreateFile(  FILE_NAME,
                        GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
                        FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                        NULL,
                        OPEN_ALWAYS,
                        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                        NULL)) 
                                == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
    fprintf(stderr,"PARENT: Unable to open file %s: %d\n",FILE_NAME,GetLastError());
    exitPrompt();
}

if((hMMap = CreateFileMapping(      hFile,
                                NULL,
                                PAGE_READWRITE,
                                0,
                                BUFF_SIZE*2,
                                "Global\\file_log_txt")) 
                                            == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"PARENT: Unable to create memory mapping: %d\n",GetLastError());

}



si_e.cb = sizeof(si_e);
si_e.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
si_e.hStdOutput =hWritePipe;
si_e.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
si_e.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

        if(!CreateProcess(  NULL,
                    "..\\Debug\\Encrypter.exe",
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    TRUE,
                    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    &si_e,
                    &pi_e))
    fprintf(stderr,"Unable to create child process.\n");








si_d.cb = sizeof(si_d);
si_d.hStdInput= hReadPipe;
si_d.hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
si_d.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
si_d.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

         if(!CreateProcess( NULL,
                    "..\\Debug\\Decrypter.exe",
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    TRUE,
                    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    &si_d,
                    &pi_d))
    fprintf(stderr,"Unable to create child process.\n");



Sleep(5000000);
return 0;
```

}

1.Process:

```
enter code here
       #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <stdio.h>
      #include <Windows.h>
          #include "..\\def.h"
              int main()
       {
int i;
HANDLE writeHandle;
HANDLE hFile, hMMap;
DWORD bytesToWrite,bytesWritten,a=50;
char * pFile, *start;
char message[50][15];   
char code[]=" ";
int index;
writeHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    if((hMMap = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,"Global\\file_log_txt")) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"Unable to create memory mapping: %d\n",GetLastError());

}

if( ( pFile = (char *) MapViewOfFile(hMMap,FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,0,0,BUFF_SIZE)) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Unable to create map view: %d\n",GetLastError());

}

    //student number =160201007(0+0+7=7)  +7encrypter
while(1){

    gets(code);
    for(  i=0;i<strlen(code);i++){
    code[i]=code[i]+7;
}
    bytesToWrite = strlen(code);
    bytesToWrite++;
    WriteFile(writeHandle,code,bytesToWrite,&bytesWritten,NULL);

}
start = pFile;
*(pFile)=*(pFile)+50;
while(pFile < start+ 100){
        *(pFile=pFile+80);
    *(pFile++) = 'A';
    break;  
}
system("pause");
return 0;
             }
```

2.process:

```
enter code here
         #include <stdlib.h>
            #include <stdio.h>
           #include <Windows.h>
                #include "..\\def.h"
          int main()

          { 

char message[80];
int index,i;
HANDLE hFile, hMMap;
char * pFile, *start;
    if((hMMap = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,"Global\\file_log_txt")) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"Unable to create memory mapping: %d\n",GetLastError());

}

if( ( pFile = (char *) MapViewOfFile(hMMap,FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,0,0,BUFF_SIZE)) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Unable to create map view: %d\n",GetLastError());

}


    for(index = 0;(message[index]=getchar()) != 0;index++);
    for(  i=0;i<strlen(message);i++){
    message[i]=message[i]-7;
                 }
    printf("Decrypter : %s\n",message);
start = pFile;
while(pFile < start + 50){

    *(pFile++) = 'A';
    break;

}
system("pause");
return 0;
           }
```

"..\def.h"

```
enter code here

          #ifndef __DEF_H
          #define __DEF_H
          #include <Windows.h>
           #include <stdio.h>
          //#include <stdlib.h>
          #define BUFF_SIZE 1024 *64
           #define FILE_NAME "log.txt"


          void exitPrompt(){
      system("pause");
     exit(0);
              }
                  #endif
```

Comment: Can you be specific about (1) who creates the file mapping, (2) how it is created; (3) which of the four lines above fail, and (4) with what error code.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a whole lot of problems :)

First, under Windows, memory mapped files can't expand - this makes them rather unsuitable for writing log files.

Multiple views of the same file should be coherent, as long as they don't refer to a network location and you don't mix memory-mapping and normal file I/O, so it should be possible to cook up something that works... but you need some way to orchestrate your writes.

I'm afraid there's no way around some interprocess communication to do this safely. For a standard ASCII log file there definitely isn't, for a custom binary format you could possibly do some trickery with length-prefixed strings and atomic data access (though I'm not sure if atomicity can be guaranteed when writing to memory mapped files), but it would be a tricky thing to do correctly - ripe with possibilities for race conditions.

Comment: you should be able to *edit* your question, instead of answering it :)